# Can't revoke default schema privilege

Tags: postgresql

pgadmin shows the default privilege for a schema was granted to an individual user and I need to revoke privilege granted from individual users.

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA a_schema
 GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO a_user;
```

I try the following command but can't revoke the privilege.

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA a_schema
 REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM a_user;
```

Can someone show me how to revoke the default privilege schema from user?

Comment: In order to revoke existing privileges you need the standalone command. See the documentation: [REVOKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-revoke.html). What you have done to to set up revoking the privileges on all future tables.

Comment: Your command is correct.

Comment: What makes you think that that doesn't work?  Are you getting an error?  Are the default priv settings still there?  Are the pre-existing privs still there?  (As belayer says, this will not remove the already existing ones)

Comment: Because pgadmin still shows the schema privilege granted to a_user.